# Can I password protect an NFS share?

Tags: security, nfs, password-protection

I have two machines on a local network (Ubuntu 11.04). I created an NFS server on machine `A`. The other machine `B` receives its IP through DHCP.

I want to know if IP is the only way to allow or deny hosts from accessing the NFS share. Is there some way I can restrict access to the NFS share based on a password?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Without involving an authentication method like [Kerberos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29), NFS on its own has very little in the way of access control - pretty much just restriction by IP address as you noted.

More info here if you want to look at the Kerberos option:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NFSv4Howto

Comment: Is there anything similar to NFS you would recommend, with authentication methods?

Comment: cifs or Common Internet Filesystem has security

Comment: @maxisme FYI May also be helpful:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412596/alternatives-to-nfs-that-rely-on-username-password-or-public-key-authenthication